# How upload user-roles.properties in Jboss 6 using CLI

Tags: jboss, jboss6.x, jboss-cli

I need create few login module in jboss.

So first I'm created module

```
/subsystem=security/security-domain=sn-security-domain/:add(cache-type=default)
```

And next command is add params

```
/subsystem=security/security-domain=sn-security-domain/authentication=classic:add(login-modules=[{"code"=>"UsersRoles", "flag"=>"required", "module-options"=>[("usersProperties"=>"path-to-file"),("rolesProperties"=>"path-to-file"),("unauthenticatedIdentity"=>"nobody")] }] )
```

Where path-to-file - is path to my file.
So question is: can I upload this file to server using CLI for example with **--resources=** param or something like that?

Ex: I can add module

```
module add --name=com.filter --resources= C:\activation.jar --dependencies=javax.servlet.api,javax.api,org.slf4j.jcl-over-slf4j
```

And it will create module on server and upload activation.jar there.

I want the same functionality for login module.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you have to manually create the files on the server.

Comment: It's a pity. Maybe it's some way to copy it to server using CLI?